# Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- broken

Tags: c, compiler-errors, raspberry-pi, ros

**I am having a problem with the installation of a ROS packages on my raspberry pi 3. I really hope you can help me.**

<== Finished processing package [10 of 53]: 'fzi_icl_core'

==> Processing plain cmake package: 'fzi_icl_can'
==> Building with env: '/opt/ros/kinetic/env.sh'
==> cmake /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/fzi_icl_can -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/kinetic -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G Unix Makefiles in '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/fzi_icl_can/install'

The C compiler identification is unknown

-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2

-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc

**-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- broken**

CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):

** The C compiler "/usr/bin/cc" is not able to compile a simple test program.**

It fails with the following output:

Change Dir: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/fzi_icl_can/install/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_cd4f1/fast"

/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_cd4f1.dir/build.make
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_cd4f1.dir/build

make[1]: Entering directory
  '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/fzi_icl_can/install/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_cd4f1.dir/testCCompiler.c.o

/usr/bin/cc -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_cd4f1.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c
  /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/fzi_icl_can/install/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c

cc1: internal compiler error: in next_pass_1, at passes.c:1258

Please submit a full bug report,

with preprocessed source if appropriate.

See  for instructions.

CMakeFiles/cmTC_cd4f1.dir/build.make:65: recipe for target
  'CMakeFiles/cmTC_cd4f1.dir/testCCompiler.c.o' failed

make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_cd4f1.dir/testCCompiler.c.o] Error 1

make[1]: Leaving directory
  '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/fzi_icl_can/install/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

Makefile:126: recipe for target 'cmTC_cd4f1/fast' failed

make: *** [cmTC_cd4f1/fast] Error 2

CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/fzi_icl_can/install/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/fzi_icl_can/install/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
<== Failed to process package 'fzi_icl_can': 
  Command '['/opt/ros/kinetic/env.sh', 'cmake', '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/fzi_icl_can', '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/kinetic', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-G', 'Unix Makefiles']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/fzi_icl_can && /opt/ros/kinetic/env.sh cmake /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/fzi_icl_can -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/kinetic -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G 'Unix Makefiles'

Command failed, exiting.

---

The output was:
1
cc1: internal compiler error: in next_pass_1, at passes.c:1258

### Please submit a full bug report,

Comment: reinstall cc compiler should solve the problem.

Comment: try to use `apt-get install gcc`

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help, it still shows the same error. Any other idea?

Answer (score 5):

If you haven't already, I would try `sudo apt-get install build-essential` to make sure that all the necessary build components are installed.

Answer (score 1):

Search installed gcc libs:

```
dpkg -l | grep libgcc | cut -d' ' -f 3 | tr '\n' ' '
```

My result:

```
libgcc-5-dev:amd64 libgcc1:amd64
```

Reinstall it:

```
apt install --reinstall libgcc1:armhf libgcc-5-dev:armhf
```